# jQuery - responsive wrap and unwrap / unwrap and undo it

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

There are elements wrapped in a "a" tag with WordPress PHP permalink and Fancybox date type, like this:

```
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="example" id="exampleid" data-fancybox-type="iframe">
    <div class="exampledivclass">
    ... some images, some divs etc ...
    </div>
</a>
```

On small screens, I want to replace the "a" tag with a "span" tag with a class.

I want to use this code:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    var wi = $(window).width();

    if (wi <= 480){

        CODE

        }
    else {

        CODE

    }
});
```

But I have no idea how to replace the "a" tag and undo that. The problem I have: How to redo the "a" tag with the right permalinks?

Is there a "undo at else what you have done at if" function in jQuery?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your HTML markup is not valid, anchor tag shouldn't get as child any block element as DIV. BTW, instead of replacing anchor tag with a SPAN, you could just replace the href attribute with e.g data-href attribute, but depending what are you looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are dealing with a simple anchor element then

```
var ahtml = $('#exampleid').clone().empty().prop('outerHTML');
$(window).resize(function () {
    var wi = $(window).width();
    if (wi <= 480) {
        $('#exampleid').replaceWith(function () {
            return $('<span />', {
                id: this.id
            }).append(this.children);
        })
    } else {
        $('#exampleid').replaceWith(function () {
            return $(ahtml).append(this.children);
        })
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/HgQBy/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [replaceWith](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/) function

For eg:

```
$('a').replaceWith( "<span>" + $( this ).text() + "</span" );
```

or

```
$('a').replaceWith( "<span>" + $( this ).html() + "</span" );
```

or other way, you can read the documentation about that on provided link.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
But how can I replace the span at the else section with the right permalink php code?